# Spark 1.2.1 fails to compile the assembly project

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-1.2

Just downloaded Spark 1.2.1 and it fails to compile in the assembly project with the following error:

```
The requested profile "hadoop-2.6" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spark-assembly_2.10: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.spark:spark-assembly_2.10:pom:1.2.1: Failure to find org.apache.spark:spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11:jar:1.2.1
```

Here is environment:

1. Hadoop 2.6.0 -- installed via brew
2. Hive 0.14.0 -- installed via brew
3. Spark 1.2.1 Downloaded as a tgz, since Brew complains about beeline being a common binary
4. Scala 2.11 -- installed via brew
5. sbt 0.13.7 -- installed via brew

I am compiling the spark distribution using the following arguments:
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package

```
Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM .......................... SUCCESS [  3.525 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................ SUCCESS [02:56 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Bagel ............................... SUCCESS [ 17.102 s]
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX .............................. SUCCESS [ 45.246 s]
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library .......................... SUCCESS [01:22 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ............................... SUCCESS [ 11.457 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Networking .......................... SUCCESS [  6.121 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Shuffle Streaming Service ........... SUCCESS [  5.642 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ........................... SUCCESS [01:19 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................ SUCCESS [01:27 min]
[INFO] Spark Project SQL ................................. SUCCESS [01:19 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................ SUCCESS [01:20 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................ FAILURE [  0.396 s]
[INFO] Spark Project External Twitter .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Sink ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External ZeroMQ ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Parent POM ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Stable API ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Shuffle Service ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Hive Thrift Server .................. SKIPPED
```

Did I miss something? I didn't want to use brew to install Apache-Spark as I will have to unlink hive and I want to use it too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `hadoop-2.4` profile, but keep the other Hadoop versions as 2.6.0:

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

Source: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201412.mbox/%3CCAMAsSdLVO73-YRa8-k_SXN5kkDKML-nKpPhgnQ3TgxUVnCp=bg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Same error, the problem seems to be with the missing dependency.

Failure to find org.apache.spark:spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11:jar:1.2.1